# Opening RStudio in a docker container

Tags: docker, rstudio

I am trying to use RStudio within a docker container.

I have created the container via shell commands:

```
docker run -e PASSWORD=<password> --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/rstudio
```

And I have retrieved the ip address via

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' rstudio
```

The above code generates the ip address `172.17.0.3` which I enter in my browser as `http://172.17.0.3:8787/`, but this only produces "This site can’t be reached".

I'm not sure what do do next?

Comment: won't it be `localhost:8787`?